# WSO2 - connectivity to WS02 Data services/ESB through custuom UI

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I need to create a custom user interface using extJS/JSP which will allow me to do following

1) create a data service using UI similar to carbon UI and deploy it.

2) create a esb service using UI similar to carbon UI and deploy it.

I could not find API available which can be integrated with other user interface and provide this functionality.

Ashish

Comment: have you solved this? I have the same problem but I don't know how to use the suggested "admin services", I can't find any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own UI. This is possible with a design feature we have, which is called frontend/backend separation. Basically for each component, we have a front end UI component and a core backend component. And these two communicate with each other using web services. Basically a backend component exposes its functionalities from secure web services, which we call "admin services". These admin services are called from the front end component's JSPs. So if you write our own UI logic from JSP or any other technology, you will just need to have a way of calling those secured admin web services to get the functionality you need. Basically all the functionality like, saving a data service, a ESB proxy service and all can be done using these admin services. For the Carbon 3.2.x platform, the WSDLs for the admin services and projects to build Java service stubs can be found here https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0/service-stubs.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Thanks. If I am able to invoke thsese services then that should be fine. I am hoping to try this soon.

Comment: could make an example of using one of these services from a JSP page?

Answer (score -1):

You can use carbon studio(Now the WSO2 Developer Studio).

Comment: I though carbon studio is a developer tool which allows me to create esb and data service.

Comment: I though carbon studio is a developer tool which allows me to create esb and data service.  I need to develop replacement UI for carbon "management console" which will allow users to use to create dataservice, ESB service   and deploy them using my custom "management console" user interface.